# Solution of this recurrence relation

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, recurrence-relations, trees, stirling-numbers

I am trying to find solution of this recurrence 
$T(n+1,k+1) = T(n,k) + k \times \left( T(n,k+1) \right)$

Is T(n+1,k+1) = S(n,k) ? Based on this interpretation I have verified for many values given a tree. It is still very difficult for me to prove. S(n,k) is Stirling number of second kind.

Based on my recollection, @Gautam gave a  very interesting interpretation for this a long time ago. He suggests that T(n+1,k+1) is the number of k independent vertices set for n vertices tree. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)

I think I could justify this  in a similar way to Stirling number of second kind proof. But here, we get $k \times T(n,k+1)$ because while adding a leaf you could add the newly added vertex in k number of ways to form independent sets.

Answer (score 1):

[Stirling numbers of the second kind $S(n,k)$ satisfy the same recurrence relation as $T(n+1,k+1)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Recurrence_relation), so the 
$T(n+1,k+1)=S(n,k)$ provided you have the coincidence at initial conditions.

The number of $k>2$ independent vertices set for $n$-vertex tree depends on a tree. For instance, if a tree is a path and $k>\lceil n/2\rceil$, there is no such sets. From the other hand, for $n>k\ge 2$ a star with $n-1$ leaves has ${n-1 \choose k}$ such sets. For $n\ge k=2$ such sets are all (unordered) pairs of distinct vetices of the tree (which number is ${n \choose 2}$), but pairs of adjacent verices (which number is exactly the number of edges of the tree, that is $n-1$). So in this case the number of such sets eqauls $${n \choose 2}-(n-1)={n \choose 2}-{n-1 \choose 1}={n-1 \choose 2}.$$

Comment: In a path tree for $k>\lceil n/2\rceil$ there are sets. E.g n=9 , k=5. {2},{4},{6}, {8}, {1,3,5,7,9} . For a star with n-1 leaves, it is S(n-1,k-1) not {n-1 \choose k}.

Comment: @T.Harish So by “the number of $k$ independent vertices set for $n$ vertices tree” $T$ you mean a number of partitions of the vertex set $V$ of the tree $T$ into $k$ subsets, each of which is independent, but not a number of independent subsets of size $k$ of $V$, as I understood? PS. $\lceil 9/2\rceil=5\not >5$.

Comment: Sorry I meant, the vertices in a set should all be independent. That is the only condition. Between two sets there could be independence or not